# Ionic - how to change textfield background colour?

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I already set textfield background colour into transparent but not working in Ionic.

```
.item .item-input {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

I already read the Ionic documentation but it's not working. It's still white colour.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#forms-inline-labels

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you sure your css rule matches the correct element?

Your rule:

```
.item .item-input {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Matches an element with class item-input, which is a descendant of an element with class item. Perhaps you meant the following?:

```
.item.item-input {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

This rule matches an element with class item **and** item-input.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular (as your question has an Angular tag), the answer is to use **--background**

```
--background: transparent !important; // example
```

[image]

see https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#css-custom-properties (select : Angular from the list to see Angular related docs)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit of a hack, but could you put the text inside another div and give the div a special background colour.

So, something like this:

```
.text {
background-colour: red; // or colour: red; I don't know
}
```

and then put the text between this div. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -3):

```
.label {
background-color: reba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
}
```

Then put the CSS rule on the ion-item element like this:

```
<ion-item class="label">
```

Comment: Do you mean `rgba`? Because `reba` is not a valid declaration for colors.